# add a object of a class extends jpanel in a frame in same class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

i'm trying to make a class that when we make an object of this class in main method show a window with cyan color

in my last programs i wrote a class extends jpanel (example:`Test extends JPanel`) and then in main class i just add a object of Test in a Frame 
but now i wanna do it in Test

generally just with making an object of Test class i want to see a cyan window here is my incomplete code :

```
public class BoardFrame extends JPanel {    
    private int rowNumber,columnNumber;
    private JFrame mainFrame;   
    public BoardFrame(int m,int n){ 
        rowNumber = m;
        columnNumber = n;           
        mainFrame = new JFrame();           
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);         
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.cyan);         
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. What's your problem? Is it how to create an instance of `BoardFrame`?

Comment: you can use `setBackground(Color.cyan);`

Comment: Btw, you'll probably want to set the color on `g` _before_ rendering it by calling `super.paintComponent(g)`.

Comment: @fastSnail  its a part of biger project so i dont want to do it

Comment: im a beginner pls give example codes

Comment: @AliZeynali you are just set color but you are not drawing anything

Comment: @fastSnail it's a test class i will do it after solve this problem

Comment: totally unclear .you have to show specific problem here.no one will complete codes for you

Comment: `Test` ? what is Test  object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is `mainFrame.add(this);` before you do `mainFrame.setVisible(true);`

If you want to use the `g.setColor(Color.cyan);`, you have to draw something.

Use `g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());`
Or you can just use `this.setBackground(Color.cyan);` in the constructor.

Here is your complete fixed code. Try it out!

```
public class BoardFrame extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BoardFrame();
    }

    private int rowNumber, columnNumber;
    private JFrame mainFrame;

    public BoardFrame(int m, int n) {
        rowNumber = m;
        columnNumber = n;
        mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      //this.setBackground(Color.cyan); // replaces need for paintComponent
        mainFrame.add(this); // <-- added this line
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.cyan);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight()); // <-- added this line
    }
}
```

Comment: look at my constructor it get two parameters and new a frame so

Comment: Did you try doing what I said? The new frame you created needs to add the JPanel `this` for it to display.

Comment: I added complete fixed code to my answer if you want to try it out.

Comment: You should not call setBackground() in the paintComponent() method. You should just call `this.setBackground(Color.cyan)` in your constructor and eliminate the paintComponent() override completely.